# In Oracle, get count of unique occurrences of one field base on another field

Tags: oracle

I have a table in an Oracle database that looks something like this:

```
ID1      ID2
 1        4
 1        4
 2        3
 1        5
 2        5
 3        6
```

Essentially, I want to write a query that will give a count of the number of ID1,ID2 pairs where ID2 is unique to ID1. In my example above, the query would return:

```
ID1      countOfUniqueID2Pairs
 1                 1
 2                 1
 3                 1
```

This would be the result because each ID1 only has one ID2 that is unique to it (1 to 4, 2 to 3, 3 to 6).

Would anyone know how to go about writing this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( ID1, ID2 ) AS (
  SELECT 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 6 FROM DUAL
);
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT ID1,
       COUNT( DISTINCT ID2 )
FROM   TABLE_NAME
WHERE  ID2 IN ( SELECT ID2
                FROM   TABLE_NAME
                GROUP BY ID2
                HAVING   COUNT( DISTINCT ID1 ) = 1 )
GROUP BY ID1;
```

**Results**:

```
       ID1 COUNT(DISTINCTID2)
---------- ------------------
         1                  1 
         2                  1 
         3                  1
```

**Update - Query 2**:

```
SELECT ID1,
       COUNT( DISTINCT ID2 )
FROM   (
  SELECT ID1,
         ID2,
         COUNT( DISTINCT ID1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY ID2 ) AS CNT1
  FROM   Table_Name
)
WHERE  CNT1 = 1
GROUP BY ID1;
```

Comment: This looks to be the right query, but is there another method that would be faster? The table I'm running this on is very large (billions of records).

Comment: Added a second query that will not do two full scans of the table (instead using a single table scan and an analytical function).

Comment: Much faster! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same result using id2 as pivot:

```
SELECT t2.id1
     , count(distinct t.id1) "countOfUniqueID2Pairs"
  FROM table_name t
    INNER JOIN table_name t2
      ON t2.id2 = t.id2
  GROUP BY t.id2, t2.id1
  HAVING count(distinct t.id1) = 1
```

Comment: Try adding a row with `id1=3,id2=7` to the data. The expected result is a count of `2` for `id1=3` but this query will get two rows where `id1=3` each with a count of `1`.